# How to use arrow's string parsing, and simultaneously set a timezone?

Tags: python, datetime, python-arrow

I would like, using `arrow`, to parse dates from strings. I do it via [the documented way](http://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#creation):

```
>>> arrow.get('2013-05-05 12:30:45', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
<Arrow [2013-05-05T12:30:45+00:00]>
```

The string is parsed with the timezone `+00:00`. **Is it possible to force another timezone for this string?**

Converting to the local timezone afterwards

```
>>> arrow.get('2013-05-05 12:30:45', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').to('local')
<Arrow [2013-05-05T14:30:45+02:00]>
```

is not the right solution, as the date is first parsed to `+00:00`, then converted to another timezone - and the hour is modified accordingly (which is the expected behaviour for `.to()`)

Comment: Not sure, but from docs you can pass `tzinfo=tz.tzlocal()`

Comment: @dnit13: you are correct. I did not realize that one could add `tzinfo` when parsing a string (though I should have tried). If you could please turn you comment into an answer I would be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Passing](http://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#arrow.factory.ArrowFactory.get) `tzinfo=tz.tzlocal()` in get method will do it:

```
>>> import arrow
>>> from dateutil import tz
>>> arrow.get('2013-05-05 12:30:45', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss', tzinfo=tz.tzlocal())
<Arrow [2013-05-05T12:30:45+02:00]>
```

Answer (score 1):

With version 1.2.3+, you can just use `'local'` for `tzinfo`:

```
arrow.get('2013-05-05 12:30:45', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss', tzinfo='local')
```